# is this best way of type conversion

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, type-conversion

I want to covert data from one type (Test1) of another one (Test2). I can do it with a method in Test1 class as shown below.

```
public class Test1
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }

    public Test2 ConvertToTest2()
        {
            // ............
        }       
}

public class Test2
{
    public float Alpha { get; set; }
    public float Beta  { get; set; }
}

Test1 test1 = new Test1() { x=1, y=2, z=3 };
Test2 test2 = test1.ConvertToTest2();
```

I know there are other mechanism (`IConvert`, `Convert`, `TypeConverter` etc). I wonder what I am doing is the best approach? If there are other approaches better suited for this, can you please suggest how to accomplish that?

Comment: What problems are you having with what you are doing?  In what way is the program unsatisfactory?

Comment: class can have other complex type, i just put a simple example. Point is what will be best mechanism of type conversion because seem like there are several options.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question.

Comment: then please explain your question. I am only trying to understand if any of other mechanism will be better suited for such scenario

Comment: None of the types you mentioned in your question deal with converting a `Test1` instance to a `Test2` instance - they'd be helpful for converting the individual numerical components between classes. Your only other "standard" option is to define a cast between the classes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You haven't explained what problems you are having with the solution that you have.  SO is for specific programming problems, you need to actually have a problem to solve, and currently you haven't indicated that you have any problem to solve.

Comment: how come Heinzi was able to come up with an answer if this wasn't explained well?

Comment: @Servy: The implicit question seems to be "Is this idiomatic C#?" or "Is there a community consensus or established best-practice guideline on where to put type conversion code?", both of which seem perfectly fine to me. Granted, the question would be on-topic on codereview.stackexchange.com as well.

Comment: @PaulSnow He hasn't given an answer to your problem, because of course you don't have a problem.  That he posted something that is labeled an answer doesn't make it one.

Comment: @Servy: How is "yes" not a valid answer to a yes/no question?

Comment: @Heinzi Because it doesn't solve the actual problem, which of course it can't do because *there is none*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly fine. I'd call the method just `ToTest2`, since this seems to be the convention established by the .net library (compare, e.g., to `ToString`, `ToList`, `ToArray`, ...).

Comment: Thanks for prompt response and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Though your approach is good, I find extension methods very good for type conversions. They allow to keep types unaware of each other, and stay focused on their business responsibilities. Currently your `Test1` class does not adhere to Single Responsibility principle. It has two reasons to be changed - if it's data or logic changes, or if conversion to `Test2` changes (e.g. property renamed, removed, or some conversion rule changed).

So, here is how extension method can look:

```
public static Test2 ToTest2(this Test1 source)
{
    return new Test2 {
        // ...
    };
}
```

Usage will stay same:

```
var test1 = new Test1() { x=1, y=2, z=3 };
var test2 = test1.ToTest2();
```

You also should think about usage of some mapping tool, like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). It automatically maps properties with same names, and allows you to specify custom mapping rules. Mapping will look like:

```
var test2 = Mapper.Map<Test2>(test1);
```